# What script should I use to build a image hotspot with correct and incorrect choice zones to click on

Tags: graphs, charts, jquery

I need an image to be plotted as a graph in jQuery or any other platform. There will be one or multiple predefined areas in the graph where the user can click to get the choice as right. If he clicks on any other zone, he will make a wrong choice <s>which will be indicated by a red marker ( for the right choice , it will be  a green marker)</s>.

You can **find a demo** of what I said by  following  the below path :

1) Go [here](http://www.accaglobal.com/gb/en/student/exam-support-resources/fundamentals-exams-study-resources/f7/cbe-specimen-exams.html)

2) Click on 'Full specimen Exam'

3) Click on the 'Next' link located at the right bottom corner of  the page

4) Now you have to click on the 'Next' button on a consecutive pages (4-5) one after another. Beware that you have to scroll down to the page (i.e. to confirm  that you have viewed the whole page) to make the 'Next' button work.

5) After a few pages ,at a certain page, you will click on the 'Next' button and the exam will start after showing you a confirmation box.

6)After the exam starts you will see a 'Navigator' link at the right bottom corner of the page. Click on the link and go to 'Question no 7'. You will find the interactive graph there.

I tried to look up the script in the `view source` of the page but in vain.

Any recommendations as to which script or tool should I use to build such a hot spot graph chart in **jQuery** or any other tool ?

**Edit:** I am uploading an image as to how the graph  looks like in the site I mentioned:

### [image]

**Edit 2:** When the user makes a selection by clicking on a point, that point will be saved in the database. Later it will be checked against the correct answer.